# Why does eig(A) function (in which A is a positive semidefinite function) returns negative doubles?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

If we generate `b=randn(10,1)`,  the matrix `A=b*b'` must be a positive semi-definite matrix and therefore all its eigenvalues must be >=0.

When I use `eig(A)` function, it returns doubles like `-3.6934e-16` and ... (negative doubles).

Is there any way to increase the precision? Is it safe to round them to absolute zero?

thanks.

Edit: I removed an irrelevant part.

Comment: Dennis answered your question. But in terms of the error from `iwishrnd`, even if you somehow perturbed your matrix `A` so that non of the eigenvalue were tiny negative values, would you really get reasonable results? I know nothing about `iwishrnd`, but the documentation says that it requires a positive definite matric. Your `A` matrices are not positive definite. So why would you expect it to work at all?

Comment: you are right and thanks a lot. this means absolute zeros will not solve the problem :( I should think of sth else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a rounding issue, when you have a vector of which some elements are 16 orders of magnitude smaller than others it is quite safe to just round them to zero in matlab.