# Why does matlab call A, in iwishrnd(A,df) function, a covariance matrix?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I get this error when I call iwishrnd() function:
`??? Error using ==> iwishrnd at 41

Covariance matrix must be symmetric and positive definite.`
as I explained in my previous question:
[Why does eig(A) function (in which A is a positive semidefinite function) returns negative doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478359/why-does-eiga-function-in-which-a-is-a-positive-semidefinite-function-return)

I like to know, why matlab calls this parameter a *Covariance matrix* ?

I know that, this matrix is used as the conjugate prior for the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution, but it is proportional to mean of that covariance matrix (as you can see in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution). So, isn't it better to call this the mean of the distribution, instead of the covariance matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nomenclature issue; it's relatively common to call the A parameter in the Wishart distribution a 'covariance matrix', since it (1) has to have all the properties of a covariance matrix, (2) the output of the Wishart distribution is almost always used as a covariance matrix (e.g., the Wishart is the conjugate prior for a Gaussian, see link below) and (3) A represents the mean of the expected covariance matrix output from the Wishart distribution.

A does not represent the covariance of the Wishart distribution, if that's what you're wondering.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions